# how to troubleshoot docker network issues?

Tags: docker

I have a new ubuntu system and learning to use docker to serve web stuff, and I can ssh into from my laptop. how can I troubleshoot connecting docker to local network?

diagram:

```
          [router]
             |
    +------------------+
    |                  |
[laptop:macos]  [server:ubuntu]
```

if I run on the server:

```
> docker run --rm -it -u root  -p 80:80  strm/helloworld-http
```

then on the server run I can hit the docker server:

```
> curl localhost
<html><head><title>HTTP Hello World</title>...
```

but from my laptop via local network:

```
> curl http://172.*.*.*
<error cannot connect>
```

but if I run on the server a simple python script instead of docker:

```bash
> sudo python3 -m http.server 80
```

I can hit it from my laptop:

```
> curl http://172.*.*.*
<expected web page content success>
```

docker appears to be unable to connect to the network, or lacks permission to serve externally.

- but it can successfully pull any data needed to build images
- there are no firewalls setup on this machine yet
- python servers can emit data over the same ip and ports, just not docker

Comment: found a possible matching problem: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/13914

Answer (score 0):

solved on ubuntu by

```
sudo systemctl edit docker.service
```

and setting the ExecStart to have `--ip=<machine ip>`